# java filecopy program for .pdf files getting currupted file in output

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I wrote this program to copy one pdf file to other but I'm getting curupt fiel in o/p for .txt files this code is working fine.

**code:**

```
public class FileCopy {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("C:\\dev1.pdf");
            byte b;
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\dev2.pdf");
            while ((b = (byte) fs.read()) != -1) {
                os.write(b);
            }
            os.close();
            fs.close();
        } catch (Exception E) {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that I'm reading the data byte by byte , because when I'm using read(byte []) method the code is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are mixing ints and bytes. This should work as expected:

```
int b;
while ((b = fs.read()) != -1) {
    os.write(b);
}
```

In particular, when `fs.read()` returns 255, `(byte) fs.read` returns -1.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
try {          
   FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("C:\\dev1.pdf");

   FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\dev2.pdf");
   while ((int b = (byte) fs.read()) != -1) {
       os.write(b);
   }
   os.close();
   fs.close();
} catch (Exception E) {
    E.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer though. try to add some explanation to your answer in future.